# Is device's orientation event dead?

Tags: javascript, web

Is 'ondeviceorientation' event dead for moblie? Because mobile (android) Chrome (latest) does not react for this code:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function() {console.log('event')});
```

Desktop Chrome works fine. If that's dead, is there another way to mobile parallax with the device's API?

Comment: i hope not as you can see this ,  http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_orientation.asp

Comment: and using query, this  http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_orientationchange.asp

Comment: Elements of browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent#Specifications @KishoreSahas I think OP is not using jQuery here : )

Comment: jQuery'es 'orientationchange' != 'deviceorientation' @KishoreSahas

Comment: only diff is you need jQuery mobile library included , see this demos http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_orientationchange and http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_events_orientationchange

Comment: deviceorientation is part of the W3C spec from just four years ago so, no, I don't think it's dead: http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#deviceorientation

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: @KishoreSahas i want get X, Y and Z device's coords not portrait/landscape only.

Comment: That's depending on the version of android are you using, but this table said really compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent#Browser_compatibility . You said "chrome doesn't react to this code". How do you are testing it? With `console.log` you need to access the console of your device with some tools that allows you.

Answer (score 0):

It's really dead.
Proof: http://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html

try from mobile Chrome.